Why $A^{(2)} \oplus B^{(2)} \not\cong A^{(3)} \oplus B^{(3)}$ where $A$ and $B$ are simple right $R$-modules.
Excuse me for this naive question. Let $A_R$ and $B_R$ be simple modules. I know that there can not be an isomorphism $A^{(2)} \oplus B^{(2)} \cong A^{(3)} \oplus B^{(3)}$. One reason of this fact is to use the cancellation property of the simple modules. However, I need a straightforward self-contained explanation.
Another attempt: I said that if there is an isomorphism $A^{(2)} \oplus B^{(2)} \cong A^{(3)} \oplus B^{(3)}$, then we get
\begin{align}
M_2(D) \times M_2(D') &\cong End(A^{(2)}) \times End(B^{(2)}) \\
 &\cong End(A^{(2)} \oplus B^{(2)}) \\
&\cong End(A^{(3)} \oplus B^{(3)}) \\
&\cong End(A^{(3)}) \times End(B^{(3)}) \\
&\cong M_3(D) \times M_3(D')
\end{align}
, where $D=End(A)$ and $D'=End(B)$ are division rings. But I do not know how to get a contradiction from this.

It's simpler than this. If $M$ is a semisimple module and $A$ is a simple module, then the multiplicity of $A$ in $M$ is $\dim_{\text{End}(A)} \text{Hom}(A, M)$ (this is a right $\text{End}(A)$-module). This is an isomorphism invariant, and is different for your two modules.
